# how to proper use c++ std:barrier?

Tags: c++, concurrency

Anyone can find where the bug is in following program ? the program will print the number from 1 to 30 . main thread gernerate the number and push it into the queue, other 10 threads get number from the queue and print it . the point is the main thread must wait until others threads print first 10 numbers ,then second and third.

```
thread_local int k=0;
void test(std::stop_token t ,std::barrier<> &b,std::queue<int> & p,std::mutex& m,std::condition_variable& cnd){
    int i=-9999;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> uk(m,std::defer_lock) ;
    while(true){
        uk.lock() ;
        cnd.wait(uk,[&]{return !p.empty() || t.stop_requested();});
        if(t.stop_requested()){
            uk.unlock() ;
            break;
        }
        i = p.front();
        p.pop();
        std::cout << "thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " k: " << ++k << " i: "<< i << std::endl ;
        uk.unlock() ;
        b.arrive_and_wait() ;
    }
    std::cout << "finished" << std::endl;
}


int main(){
    std::barrier workDone(11) ;
    std::vector<std::jthread> threads;
    std::queue<int> procs;
    std::mutex m ;
    std::stop_source r ;
    std::stop_token t{r.get_token()} ;
    std::condition_variable cnd ;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        threads.emplace_back(std::jthread(test,t,std::ref(workDone),std::ref(procs),std::ref(m),std::ref(cnd)));
    }

    int p=1;
    int j=0;
    while(true){
        procs.push(p) ;
        cnd.notify_one() ;
        if(p % 10 == 0){
            workDone.arrive_and_wait() ;
            ++j ;
            if(j==3){
                r.request_stop() ;
                break;
            }
        }
        ++p ;
    }
    cnd.notify_all() ;
    std::cout << "end" << std::endl ;
}
```

run 10000 times the program ,9999 successed,1 failed......

when failed,the output stuck forever like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaNjC.png)

I can't find where the bug is,anyone can help me?

Comment: One problem is that `std::queue` is not thread-safe, and you do not protect it in the main thread. `procs.push(p)` should be likely executed under the locked mutex.

Comment: yes,you are right,I fixed and add a new line "std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms)"before cnd.nofity_all(); the stuck disappeared